# How to sort inbound props in a ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS component that has a prop that is a collection.

I want to ensure this collection is always sorted for the component.

Where should I place the sorting logic?

Putting it inside the JSX will mean it is run on every render, which is inefficient.

```
class MyComponent {
    render() {
        const { collection } = this.props; // I want collection to stay sorted
        return <div>collection.map(i => <div>i</div>)</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not sort it wherever you are assigning your props?

Comment: Thank you. You are correct. I now intend to add the sorting logic into mapStateToProps based on the indentity of the collection changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you can't sort it before sending it to the component, `componentWillReceiveProps` would be good for this:

```
class MyComponent {
    this.sorted = [];

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Here you can check if the collection has changed
        // and skip the sort if it hasn't.
        this.sorted = sort(nextProps.collection);
    }

    render() {...}
}
```